# How to create a custom HTML page in a Hugo website?

Tags: html, hugo, blogdown, static-site

I want to add a custom HTML page to my Hugo website [here](https://mallorydazza.netlify.app/), with its github repo [here](https://github.com/MalloryDazza/MalloryDazza_Website).

I do not want the Hugo theme to be used in this custom html page, all the needed css/javascript and some html is already in the `custom_page.html`.

I already found a useful questions/answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59678701/is-it-possible-to-add-a-single-custom-html-page-to-an-existing-hugo-theme-like-a), but it does not work for me. I do not know why... maybe I don't understand the link I have to use to point to this custom page.

**Here is what I have tried :**

I have a `custom_page.html` in the content folder (also tried in the static folder) and I add in a post `blog/_index.Rmd` the link to what I think could work with the following :
`[link](\content\custom_page.html)` (when the file is in the static folder I used : `[link](\static\custom_page.html)` )
I always end up with a `404 page not found`

Any advice on how to proceed ?

Comment: You're not going to like this answer, but you should learn the basics of hugo: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLLAZ4kZ9dFpOnyRlyS-liKL5ReHDcj4G3&v=qtIqKaDlqXo <- that's a good series. 
tldr: You need to make a layout for your page.